# How to run ./gradlew command from folder?

Tags: android, bash, gradle, gradlew

to build apk I'm running the command from terminal:

`> ./gradlew app:assembleDebug`

So I put the command to `MyProject/myBashFile.sh`and run from terminal:

`> bash myBashFile.sh`

File **myBashFile.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
./gradlew app:assembleDebug
```

But when I put the file to dir `MyProject/bushFiles/myBashFile.sh` and trying to run the command:

`> bash bushFiles/myBashFile.sh`

Error is:

`./gradlew: No such file or directory`

Comment: the `gradlew.sh` script is located in the root project directory, so if you want to execute if from a script located in a sub-directory, just change the path to `gradlew` from your script ( e.g.  `../gradlew [tasks]` in your case)

Comment: `../gradlew [tasks]` also doesn't work

Comment: I meant `./../gradlew`

Comment: @M.Ricciuti found solution `././gradlew`

Comment: `./gradlew` means `run gradlew file from current directory`. Obviously there is no such file in that *current* directory

Answer (score 0):

Found solution in result **MyProject/bushFiles/myBashFile.sh** is:

```
#!/bin/bash
././gradlew app:assembleDevelop
```